# Jest test creates empty blob object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, blob

I have a working function that builds a new Blob() in my app

```
_buildBlobForProperties(app): Blob {
   return new Blob(
        [
          JSON.stringify({
            name: app.name,
            description: app.description,
          }),
        ],
        {
          type: 'application/json',
        }
      );
}
```

And I have the following test:

```
it('should return properties for update',() => {
      const blob: Blob = appService._buildBlobForProperties(app);
      expect(blob.text()).toBe(updateBlob.text());
    });
```

This test works fine in Jasmin/Karma but when migrating the test to jest I get:

```
TypeError: blob.text is not a function
```

And when I print the content of the return Blob I get

```
console.log
    --->  Blob {}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _buildBlobForProperties() does not return a promise from what i see so why the await ?

Comment: Good point, it's obvious it's not needed once I simplified it for the example (I'm only migrating our tests, didn't write most of them :P )

Answer (score 2):

You can ju test how Blob is being called.

```
const TEST_BLOB_CONSTRUCTOR = jest.fn();

jest.spyOn(global, 'Blob').mockImplementationOnce((...args) => {
  TEST_BLOB_CONSTRUCTOR(...args);
});

expect(TEST_BLOB_CONSTRUCTOR).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  [JSON.stringify({ name: EXPECTED_NAME, description: EXPECTED_APPLICATION })], 
  { type: 'application/json' }
)
```

Comment: decent workaround if you dont want to deal with polyfills and such :D

Answer (score 1):

Jest test environment doesn't support the `Blob` object very well, see [issue#2555](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2555), I suggest you use [blob-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-polyfill) package to global patch `Blob` object in the test environment. So whether the [testEnvironment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) is `jsdom` or `node` test environment, your test cases can pass.

`service.ts`:

```
export class AppService {
  _buildBlobForProperties(app): Blob {
    return new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: app.name, description: app.description })], { type: 'application/json' });
  }
}
```

`service.test.ts`:

```
import { Blob } from 'blob-polyfill';
import { AppService } from './service';

globalThis.Blob = Blob;

describe('69135061', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const appService = new AppService();
    const app = { name: 'teresa teng', description: 'best singer' };
    const blob: Blob = appService._buildBlobForProperties(app);
    const text = await blob.text();
    expect(text).toEqual(JSON.stringify(app));
  });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69135061/service.test.ts (8.044 s)
  69135061
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.092 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"blob-polyfill": "^5.0.20210201"
```